Is there a way to trigger a Product Rule evaluation when a Quote Line record is deleted?
tl;dr - Can apex triggers or another automatic process be set up to fire CPQ Product Rules when a Quote Line record is deleted?
Background
Our org has Product Rules set up that add certain products to a quote when broader quote criteria are met. However, these automatically added products can be deleted by sales reps after they've been added, causing downstream billing issues. As far as I can see there is no way to fire a Product Rule evaluation when a Quote Line is deleted, only when a quote line is added. I'm wondering if there is a way to trigger re-evaluation when a quote line is deleted, through either Apex or another automatic functionality.
